# What's the best way to have Backbone like events (notifications) in React

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, notifications, reactjs

I would like to have Backbone events like functionality in my react application also, I'm using webpack.
Some of the examples I found are:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-events
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-events

Which one is better (and why), also if there's any other that I can use?

Similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222445/react-and-events-communication

Comment: Why would you want this? Is it because you're trying to interop a Backbone app and a React app or are you just more comfortable with Backbone events than rather with Flux actions?

Comment: It's more like Events will solve my use case in the best possible manner more than Flux actions